# Python regex put space infront of non-repeating period

Tags: python, regex

For instance given the string:

```
Reading my book... hate it... The childs is good read. This is funny.
```

It should return:

```
Reading my book... hate it... The childs is good read . This is funny .
```

Notice the space between `d` and `.`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [negative lookaround assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can filter `.`  which does not follow dot (`(?<!\.)`) and is not followed by dot (`(?!\.)`):

```
>>> text = 'Reading my book... hate it... The childs is good read. This is funny.'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)', r' .', text)  # Replace the matched dot with ` .`
'Reading my book... hate it... The childs is good read . This is funny .'
```